# rising-stars-top-50-users-ordered-on-rep-per-day query not working

Tags: support, data-explorer

I found the following question on the Stack Exchange Data Explorer:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/946/rising-stars-top-50-users-ordered-on-rep-per-day

I choose as site stackoverflow.com

I execute and got the following error:

> The data types date and datetime are incompatible in the subtract operator.

If I assume that query did run successfully before (as it is rather old) what should I do differently to get results from that query?

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/123299/rising-stars-top-50-users-ordered-on-rep-per-day

Comment: Your link works. So the link from queries should be updated?

Comment: This really isn't a meta question, it's a SQL question...

Comment: @Rob that is strictly true but if the OP isn't familiar with SQL they can't know where the problem is and it might as well be with SEDE it self. That makes the question on-topic for Meta. If you really think SQL query support questions for SEDE should be asked elsewhere make a case for it but at the moment both MSO and MSE are full of it (and most of my MSE rep comes from those type of questions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Hans](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) already [showed](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/123299/rising-stars-top-50-users-ordered-on-rep-per-day), there is an issue with the  revision of the query you found. The date type of the variable is now in conflict with the type datetime of the column.

Instead of

```
DECLARE @endDate date
```

The query should read

```
DECLARE @endDate datetime
```

The type datetime matches the type of the creationdate column in the users table and therefor the subtract operator will work, where it doesn't on incompatible types.

Although it is somewhat unfortunate that queries break after there have been changes to the datamodel or SQL version there is no real easy moderation mechanism on SEDE. Your only option is to fork the query and make the needed changes, assuming you have enough SQL skills or Google Fu to figure out what the change should be.